# Everytime I reboot my system all of my taskbar favourites are reset to defult

Tags: dual-boot, reboot, default, taskbar, reset

It only seems to effect my taskbar, but its annoying. I shove things there that I want to get quick access too. Though, Firefox keeps auto-launching just like after when I first installed the OS. I'm running dual boot on with two different internal SSD's with Ubuntu on one drive and Windows on the other, but I don't see how that would affect anything. All my other defaults are saving, like using Brave as my main browser, and having changed music app and video app. Maybe if I just lock my taskbar. I will laugh if its as simple as that.

If anyone has any suggestions anyway, it will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Added: I kind of found a work around. It was my default desktop environment causing issues. To get around it I installed a few different environments to give a try, and all of them are saving all my defaults now, and at the moment I've decided to keep using Plasma.

Comment: You haven't told us what OS & release you're talking about, nor if it's an installed or *live* system, a *guest* account etc... that all impact what you're describing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of found a work around. It was my default desktop environment causing issues. To get around it I installed a few different environments to give a try, and all of them are saving all my defaults now, and at the moment I've decided to keep using Plasma.

I believe the desktop environment I was using was suffering some kind of glitch when dealing with my taskbar, even resetting the taskbar tweak with every reboot. Hopefully this is just a one-off with me, but if anyone stumbles across this with the same issue, hopefully this will help.